# Trouble with List Iterators Incompatible in STL

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Ok I am, average at programming, I am not a professional, but I do know enough to get me around. I am having trouble with this piece of code, btw I am using Microsoft Visual 2013. Pretty much what it is saying to me its giving me a very bad bug saying that the list iterators is incompatible. So basically it doesn't like that I am comparing one thing from one list to another thing from another list. My work around was extracting both 'values' and inputting them into a different list where then I will compare the two, but that may be the hard way of doing things. Can anyone please shed some light on this for me? Thanks!!

```
list<string>::iterator cur;
list<string>::iterator dis;

cur = current_list.begin();
dis = disregard_list.begin();
unsigned int x = 1;
while (x < current_list.size()  )
{

    if (cur == dis)
    {
        cur = current_list.erase(cur);
    }
    else
    {
        ++cur;
        ++x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make your example code compilable and post the error message.

Comment: The problem is exactly what the compiler is telling you - you can't compare iterators belonging to different `list`s. You probably want `if (*cur == *dis) { ... }`

Comment: Literally that, its not an error a window comes up and says exactly List Iterator Incompatible, and references to the STL header <list>

Comment: yay that worked, thanks Praetorian!! Such a simple fix. I appreciate it!

Comment: At a guess, you're looking for the `std::set_difference` algorithm, not that this code is doing that. You might want to consider a vector as well. Lists are used very rarely.

Comment: Do you mean just `current_list.remove(disregard_list.front())`?

Comment: @KerrekSB, Maybe, but really, why is it a disregard *list* if we're just using the first element is my question.

Comment: What I suggested will get your code to compile, but I'm not sure that's the behavior you want. You'll be iterating over `current_list` and removing any items that match the first element in `disregard_list`. You'll not be comparing any other elements of `disregard_list` for matches.

Comment: @user3330589 - On a high level, what are you trying to accomplish?  What exactly are the requirements for erasure?  Writing loops to erase items in a sequence container is something you should try to avoid.  Instead, a `remove_if()` or another set of STL algorithms is all that's needed.

Answer (score 1):

Iterators `cur` and `dis` belong to different lists

```
cur = current_list.begin();
dis = disregard_list.begin();
```

So you may not compare them

```
if (cur == dis)
```

Maybe you meant something as

```
if ( *cur == *dis)
```

Also it seems that this loop

```
unsigned int x = 1;
while (x < current_list.size()  )
```

is invalid. Should the initial value of x be equal to 0?

Take into account that class `std::list` has method `remove`
Maybe you meant

```
current_list.remove( disregard_list.front() );
```

Comment: Thank you, yes that is exactly what i was looking for, but just for future reference if you were comparing two or more values in the same list you wouldn't need the pointer reference?

Comment: @user3330589, To get the value from the iterator, you need to "dereference" it. Simple as that. If you wanted to compare two *iterators* within the same container, then you wouldn't "dereference" them.

Comment: @user3330589 I am sorry. I have not understood the question. There is no pointer references.